How to sum over Slot inside MapThread
I am trying to do simple operations with several lists. In this context, I was wondering if a sum over Slot is possible inside MapThread.
Here is a simple example:
l1={{f1,ff1},{g1,gg1}};
l2={{f2,ff2},{g2,gg2}};
l0={l1,l2};

MapThread[{Slot[1][[1]], Slot[1][[2]]+Slot[2][[2]]} &, l0]
(**MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]]+#2[[2]]} &, l0]**)

which produces the expected result:

{{f1, ff1 + ff2}, {g1, gg1 + gg2}}

However, I wanted to do something like
MapThread[{Slot[1][[1]], Sum[Slot[$i][[2]],{$i,1,Length[l0]}]} &, l0]

which however does not work. I am trying to do this because then I don't have to worry about how many l1,l2,... are there inside l0.

As an alternative you could use MapAt[First, {All, 1}]@MapThread[Plus, l0, 2]

@eldo          Thanks! This works as expected. Btw, if I may ask, what is 2 for inside MapThread[Plus, l0, 2]?

I also found one small inaccuracy in this method is that when say f1=f2 or g1=g2, the Plus will result 2f1, 2g1  which will force MapAt to use Last instead of First to take out f1, g1.

Try: MapThread[{Slot[1][[1]], Total[{##}[[All, 2]]]} &, l0]

The 2 means Level 2  (see documentation for MapThread). The inaccuracy doesn't arise  with Daniels`s comment / answer.

In addition, l1 + MapAt[0 &, l2, {All, 1}]

DanielHubers's solution in the comments is nice, but another option is to deal with the structural transformation directly rather than implicitly inside of the function you're threading. So, maybe something like this:
Map[Comap[{Extract[{1, 1}], Total@*Last}], Transpose[l0, {3, 1, 2}]]

Comap is new, and the point-free style can be confusing, so an alternate might be:
Map[{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[2]]]} &, Transpose[l0, {3, 1, 2}]]

